# Algorithm security in DolphinDB

Tags: encryption, dolphindb

I have written algorithms for factor calculation, which are executed in the DolphinDB system. However, I am concerned about the security of my algorithms:

1. Can the O&M engineers of DolphinDB easily access the source code?
2. Can the frontend of the DolphinDB server intercept and access the
   source code when the algorithm is executed from the client to the
   server?

How can I ensure the confidentiality of my algorithmic code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In DolphinDB, modules, jobs, and function views in the system are
   designed with encryption, so the operations team cannot access the
   source code. You can set the configuration parameter as
   `perfMonitoring=0` to disable the monitoring of queries on DFS
   tables, further enhancing the confidentiality of your system.
2. In addition, DolphinDB supports SSL protocol, which ensures the
   confidentiality of your communication with the DolphinDB server. You
   can configure SSL in the API and server:

-API (e.g., Python API)

Specify `enableSSL=True` in the session:

```
s = ddb.Session(enableSSL=True)
```

-server
Add the configuration item `enableHTTPS=True`.